Why do the menu disappear when I add a Subdivision Surface modifier and "Apply" it to the part?
Here are some pictures of what I wonder




You'll only see the subdiv modifier as long as you don't apply it. What are you expecting for a behavior ?

I'm trying to learn Blender, and are following Blender Guru's Donut lessons

I meaned : what you described is the expected behavior for modifiers ("disappear" when applied). Could you explain to us (in your question not in comments), what you think may be an issue ? I dont't see anything wrong.

Yes, I see it now. I did not see closely enough on the video, it disappears there to. I thought it should stay there after it was applied, my mistake. Thank's anyway

As the manual says:

Apply Ctrl-A
Makes the modifier “real”: converts the object’s geometry to match the applied modifier’s results, and deletes the modifier.

The modifier is deleted and no longer exists after you apply it so its settings disappear as well.

Modifiers are automatic operations that affect an object’s geometry in
a non-destructive way. With modifiers, you can perform many effects
automatically that would otherwise be too tedious to do manually (such
as subdivision surfaces) and without affecting the base geometry of
your object.
They work by changing how an object is displayed and rendered, but not
the geometry which you can edit directly.

This means that modifiers perform some operation to the geometry(or other data) of the object continuously and display the result of it without changing the object. Once you apply it, the operation is preformed one last time this time changing the object and the modifier is then removed so you are left only with the result of it.
